# Font awesome in drupal will not dispaly icons with fa-""-""

Tags: css, drupal-7, font-awesome

I am using a Drupal theme with font awesome. I can only assume something changed because if I use an icons with the format of (fa-""-"") it will not show or shows the unicode depending on the browser.

example: the code would look like this and would work fine- icon="fa fa-truck"
if you use icon="fa fa-pie-chart" it will not show.

I do not know the terminology to explain a two word or three word icon would be called. It also works if there is a four letter icon like "fa-file-text-o"

Here is a sample page in question http://valve.park3d.com/content/11delete is there a way to fix this? I would be happy to know the terminology of what to look for.

Comment: seems like you're not loading the fonts required for font awesome; check the console, some fonts aren't located apparently

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, my issue was resolved by removing a bootstrap cdn file from header. Such as:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Or any other bootstrap cdn file you may have if you are using one.

But please note you will have to then have the actual file which you can download here:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
```

This answer is assuming you are using bootstrap as a front end framework.

In addition you may want to double check you have the CSS file for Font Awesome Icons.